# How to update Scatter point data point style?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have applied a DATAPOINT style to scatterseries that I build in code behind.
I would like the scatter points to be "bigger" in size and "Colors" to be bold. How can I achieve that? Here is the code that I have written so far:

Series creation in the code behind:

```
 ScatterSeries series;

            chart1.Series.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < model.CDFResults.Count; i++)
            {
                series = new ScatterSeries();
                series.DependentValuePath = "Value";
                series.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
                series.ItemsSource = model.CDFResults[i].FinalResult1;
                series.Title = model.CDFResults[i].categoryname;
                series.LegendItemStyle = (Style)Layout.Resources["LegendItemStyle1"];
                series.DataPointStyle = (Style)Layout.Resources["Datapointstyle1"];
                chart1.Series.Add(series);
            }
```

In the XAML:

```
 <Style x:Key="Datapointstyle1" TargetType="chartingToolkit:ScatterDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>

 <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1" Background ="White" Title="Cumulative Distributed Function Plot" FontFamily="Tahoma" >
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Tahoma" Title="Cumulative Probability"/>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
             </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Below image describes what I would like to achieve!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqbWj.png)

Comment: is this the scatter chart component from Telerik, Devexpress etc?

Comment: @GordonAllocman: I added an image that describes the issue.

Comment: @Eminem: This is WPF charting tool kit. Visual studio.

Comment: So why can't you achieve what you want in your Style? is the style not applying? It's hard to tell what the actual issue is despite your intended result being clear

Comment: @GordonAllocman: Hi Gordon. So when I change the "width" value to 50 and "height" value to 50, the points are supposed to go bigger. but nothing changes.